# Insert data on mysql using mysqli function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

how i can make a insert using this fuctions
I m learning php, as using this functions (mysqli abstract) but after update wont work any more.

```
 /** insert data array */
public function insert(array $arr)
{

    if ($arr)
    {
        $q = $this->make_insert_query($arr);
        $return = $this->modifying_query($q);
        $this->autoreset();
        return $return;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->autoreset();
        return false;
    }
}
```

complement

```
  /** insert query constructor */
    protected function make_insert_query($data)
    {
        $this->get_table_info();
        $this->set_field_types();
        if (!is_array(reset($data)))
        {
            $data = array($data);
        }
        $keys = array();
        $values = array();
        $keys_set = false;
        foreach ($data as $data_key => $data_item)
        {
            $values[$data_key] = array();
            $fdata = $this->parse_field_names($data);
            foreach ($fdata as $key => $val)
            {
                if (!$keys_set)
                {
                    if (isset($this->field_type[$key]))
                    {
                        $keys[] = '`' . $val['table'] . '`.`' . $val['field'] . '`';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $keys[] = '`' . $val['field'] . '`';
                    }
                }
                $values[$data_key][] = $this->escape($val['value'], $this->is_noquotes($key), $this->field_type($key), $this->is_null($key),
                    $this->is_bit($key));
            }
            $keys_set = true;
            $values[$data_key] = '(' . implode(',', $values[$data_key]) . ')';
        }
        $ignore = $this->ignore ? ' IGNORE' : '';
        $delayed = $this->delayed ? ' DELAYED' : '';
        $query = 'INSERT' . $ignore . $delayed . ' INTO `' . $this->table . '` (' . implode(',', $keys) . ') VALUES ' . implode(',',
            $values);
        return $query;
    }
```

before update this class i used to insert data like this

```
    $db = Sdba::table('users');
    $data = array('name'=>'adam');
    $db->insert($data);
```

this method of insert dont works on new class. 
if i try like this i got empty columns and empty values.

thanks for any help
complete class download http://goo.gl/GK3s4E

Comment: Have you enabled your error_reporting?

Comment: i get Unknown column '' in 'field list' - the method has change, but i dont figured how i need to insert using this new class.

Comment: echo your query and check it manually

Answer (score 0):

Try using set instead of insert:

```
$users = Sdba::table('users');

$user['name'] = 'Alvaro';

$users->set($user);
```

Comment: What are the columns in your Users table? have you tried to make an insert with all fields set, not just with name?

Comment: set will work like an update only if row doesn't exists, otherwise it will work like an insert.

Comment: users only have id (auto increment and name) - INSERT INTO `users` (``) VALUES ('')

Comment: Then it looks like that problem is in those functions from your code. What do you mean exactly by "but after update wont work any more" ? What kind of update?

Comment: its a mysqli abstract class. The autor give support for some time, but after update the class he never give support, the old class had couple problems (security). the new one dont have documentation. if you have interest can download complet class here http://goo.gl/GK3s4E

Comment: I guess that's the same class as from this link : http://foska.pp.ua/codecanyon/sdba/#!/features ? I will test these two functions and let you know if I came up with something useful.

Comment: This linking is the old one class - i have this.. now i m try to use the new one.